# Is there a way to apply styling to only the first displayed header row of a multipage table?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, internet-explorer-11

I'm printing out a form with a position: fixed page header, a consistently sized section of data, a small but dynamically sized section of data, then two lists. The lists correctly repeat their header rows across pages but I account for the fixed header by using padding-top. However this is also applied to the header row at the beginning on the first page, creating a large area of white-space.

The problem is mitigated on the second list by using a page-break-after: always and adjusting the title to fit the right spot.

Target platform is IE11, trying to avoid JQuery in place of JavaScript itself but open to working solutions.

I have tried pseudo-elements and pseudo-selectors to attempt to only affect the first instance but it has not shown any effect.

```
<div id="PrintDiv">
    <div id="PrintHeader">
        <asp:Label ID="lblPrintTitle" runat="server" Text="Report" CssClass="lblTitle" /><br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblPrintSource" runat="server" Text="Location" />
        <div>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Where" CssClass="lblBold" /><br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Owner" /><br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Who" /><br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Address" /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="PrintInfo">
        <asp:Label ID="lblPrintInfo" runat="server" Text="Information" />
        <table>
            <tr><td>Product:</td><td class="lblData" colspan="3"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Data 1:</td><td class="lblData"></td><td>Data 2:</td><td class="lblData"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Data 3:</td><td class="lblData"></td><td>Data 4:</td><td class="lblData"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Data 5:</td><td class="lblData"></td><td>Data 6:</td><td class="lblData"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="PrintPeople">
        <asp:Label ID="lblPrintPeople" runat="server" Text="Assigned Personnel" />
        <table></table>
    </div>
    <div id="PrintList1">
        <asp:Label ID="lblPrintList1" runat="server" Text="Some Title" />
        <asp:GridView ID="List1" runat="server" HeaderStyle-CssClass="_tblHeaders" RowStyle-CssClass="lblData" ShowHeader="true" />
    </div>
    <br style="height: 20px;" />
    <div id="PrintList2">
        <div style="position: relative;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblPrintList2" runat="server" Text="Some Title" CssClass="_Title" />
        </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="List2" runat="server" HeaderStyle-CssClass="_tblHeaders" RowStyle-CssClass="lblData" ShowHeader="true" />
    </div>
    <div id="PrintFooter" class="pFooter">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#PrintList1 th, #PrintList2 th{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 63px;
}
```

Expect to see all pages elements line up as though it is relative positioning through means of css padding.

Comment: How do you print the form? It will be better to show the screenshot of the print preview because I'm a little confused about what you want to achieve. According to your code snippet, the style will be applied to the header of PrintList1 and PrintList2. Is the style applied to somewhere else that you don't want?

Comment: I can get a screenshot made next week. I'm telling the form to print via window.print() and browser print preview. The style is applied just to the two list's ths and that's fine, but I need a way to select the first instance of the th of PrintList1 when it's printing.

When printing on page 1 the lists starts by listing the th header with padding that I want to remove and continues onto the second page and on where I do want the padding.

Comment: @YuZhou [Example Image](https://i.imgur.com/YqjjrMd.jpg) Here is a visual example of the behavior. The left side is my first page and has the header row I wish to remove the padding, the right side is a page after that which relies on the padding.

Comment: I have a doubt that is there one gridview across pages or two gridviews in two pages in your screenshot? Because in my test according to your code, if I set the print header, the gridview across the page will overlap with the header in the second page when printing and header will not appear in the second page like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jidZ.png).

Comment: My picture only shows 1 gridview, I have it's position relative and move the first row into the table's thead via C# so that it's a true header which causes it to display the header row again on following pages when it overflows. Since that is where the padding is applied it offsets the next page down below my fixed header. At this point there are 2 header rows, one at the start and another on page 2 and I need to differentiate between these in css.

Comment: I see, you have the `<th>` columns wrapped by `<thead>` tag so the title repeated every page when printing. But the `<thead>` is a whole, you can't just change the style of one instance. If you changed one, all the `<thead>` will changed when print.